# How to change FileZilla so that View/Edit opens .html in Notepad++, not Firefox

Tags: windows, filezilla

Currently Firefox is set by Windows to open .html files. I'm hoping I can sort of override this in FileZilla so I can do quick edits and then upload them to the server.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In FileZilla go to edit > settings...

In the left column scroll down to "file editing"...

Select it, then in the right column select "use custom editor" then browse to the .exe file on your comp for Notepad++.

Hope it helps. :)

[Additional Note: if you are experiencing the same problem that @theking2 has in the comment below, remember that FileZilla also imports your system's filetype associations. This may cause conflicts with your custom associations.  You can disable system associations under edit > settings > file editing > Filetype Associations: look for the checkbox. Don't forget that you did this though - it may cause other problems down the road.]

Comment: Ah, it does indeed help. But it doesn't completely work. I think that because it's *View/Edit* and somehow the system has the idea that html files are meant to viewed and not edited. However, it does work for some other stuff, like .css. Anyway, the fix: Settings > File editing > Filetype associations and enter the following custom filetype association: **html "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"**. Bam.

Comment: Doesn't work. With filezilla 3.5.1 when I select "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" as custom editor under Default editor html files are still opened in Firefox when I select Edit from context menu.

Comment: The settings are just for editing the files (note the settings page title). The `Open` context menu item [always uses](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/3726) the system filetype associations. Also note that the `Edit` option is only available when connected to a server. This is **by design**.

Answer (score 6):

Go to *Edit / Settings / File Editing / Use custom editor* (i use notepad++), then *Filetype associations / html "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"*

If you have 32-bit version of Notepad++ on a 64-bit OS then change the path to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

Pay close attention, you must specify the filetype before the full address to the application which will open it.

Answer (score 5):

In FileZilla go to edit > settings...

In the left column scroll down to "file editing"..

and then click radio button  use system's default editor for text file  and  always use default editor radio button click OK now all file be open in notepad

this help

Answer (score 4):

LiberKey -> Portable Filezilla + Portable Notepad++

```
js "..\..\..\Notepad++\Notepad++LKL.exe"
html "..\..\..\Notepad++\Notepad++LKL.exe"
css "..\..\..\Notepad++\Notepad++LKL.exe"
htm "..\..\..\Notepad++\Notepad++LKL.exe"
txt "..\..\..\Notepad++\Notepad++LKL.exe"
xml "..\..\..\..\MyApps\Office\Editor\WeBuilder\WeBuilderPortable.exe"
php "..\..\..\..\MyApps\Office\Editor\WeBuilder\WeBuilderPortable.exe"
png "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
ico "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
cur "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
jpg "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
jpeg "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
bmp "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
tif "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
tiff "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
psd "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
gif "..\..\..\FastStoneImageViewer\FastStoneImageViewerLKL.exe"
```

Answer (score 3):

Below procedure makes FileZilla to open code based file in Notepad++ and normal text based file in Notepad.

1. Open FileZilla **>** Edit Menu **>** Settings..
2. Select File editing **>** Filetype associations
3. Paste the following code in Custom filetype associations:

```
. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
php "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
/ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
html "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

4. Done..!

Please **verify the path of Notepad++**. You can set different editor for particular extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Save an html file to any place on your computer. Then go into Windows Explorer, right-click and press "properties" and then then where it says "Opens with: Firefox" press the "Change" button and select Notepad++.