# Change FileZilla settings in Ubuntu Linux so view/edit uses gedit

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, filezilla

This is similar to the Super User question *[How to change FileZilla so that View/Edit opens .html in Notepad++, not Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/89455/how-to-change-filezilla-so-that-view-edit-opens-html-in-notepad-not-firefox)*, but I am asking for FileZilla in Linux. I am using Ubuntu 10.0.4 (Lucid Lynx).

Currently my FileZilla opens files using OpenOffice. I want to change to [gedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit) for all the .log files, etc.

EDIT:

For some reason, my FileZilla has no File Edit and other settings. This is the screenshot to prove I am not blind:

[image: screenshot from FileZilla]

Comment: That's weird. Is that your whole screen, or just the FileZilla window? If that's your whole screen, can you drag FileZilla around by holding Alt?

Comment: when i use Alt+E i can find the inner menu items, but the main menu is still not there. i ve tried uninstalling and reinstalling. no use.

this will have to do for now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good enough on Linux to be able to help out with the disappearing-menu stuff :)

Comment: html /usr/bin/gedit
usun that in Filetype associations did not work for me in Ubuntu
any hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Edit` -> `Settings...`.

Scroll down to `File editing` -> `Filetype associations`.

In the `Custom filetype associations` box, add the line `html /usr/bin/gedit` (and remove any other line starting with `html`).

(Taken from [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/04/how-to-set-gedit-the-default-editor-for-filezilla-in-ubuntu-mint/) - it's Linux Mint but it should be similar enough in Ubuntu.)

Comment: thanks Rawling, problem is that my settings, are not showing up. http://picasaweb.google.com/kimcity/Screenshots#5489975181213459026