# Linux mint 12: How to view/edit files in filezilla?

Tags: linux-mint, filezilla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change FileZilla so that View/Edit opens .html in Notepad++, not Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/89455/how-to-change-filezilla-so-that-view-edit-opens-html-in-notepad-not-firefox)

Lets say I am connected to my server using filezilla, i want to edit a file `hello.php` i press `View/Edit`, Thunderbird opens and this is what i see

[image]

i have never seen this on windows, i don't know why i see this on linux, i don't know why Thunderbird opens, can you tell me what's going on?

Comment: You need to change the configuration of what application is used to open which file type, you should find [this](http://superuser.com/questions/89455/how-to-change-filezilla-so-that-view-edit-opens-html-in-notepad-not-firefox) question covers the same ground and has an answer that should provide the help you need.

Comment: @DMA57361 bro you should have asked me this question before you close the question, because i was using the default editor that filezilla uses (i think it's gedit) and i was having this issue, then i changed the editor to sublime text 2 and the issue is still there, so it's not the editor, and the question should be open

Comment: Fair enough, I'll re-open the question then, but that's the sort of thing you *really* need to say upfront in the question, otherwise people will just answer with exactly the same thing. If you don't point out what you've already tried you will get the suggestions that don't help and it's a bit of a waste of time for you and the answerers.

Comment: @DMA57361 you know what brother, feel free to close it again :) i forgot to choose `always use the default editor` instead of using `the filetype association` lol :D

Comment: Glad you're sorted now then. Post re-closed. :)