# Default .pdf-viewer for Filezilla using Mint/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, filezilla, pdf-reader, default-settings

I am currently using Filezilla 3.7.3. on Linux Mint 17 and have trouble with the default .pdf-viewer. Ones I double-click on a .pdf-file in the embedded file browser, GIMP instead of okular/evince/adobe-reader opens. I browsed through the settings of Filezilla and asked Google, but I could not find a solution.

As I found an open thread in the Filezilla forum (https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=16733) that didn't come to a solution, I decided to ask this question here and hope for help. Thanks!

Comment: When you select .pdf files at the operating system level to view which application is opened?

Comment: For that case I use Okular. Therefore, I would expect Filezilla to open that one as well...

Comment: Have you seen http://superuser.com/questions/89455/how-to-change-filezilla-so-that-view-edit-opens-html-in-notepad-not-firefox which answers a similar, but separate, question for Filezilla on Windows?

Comment: Actually I did see other questions about this issue related to text files and also saw the mentioned option in the setting. Thus, under Edit -> Settings -> File Editing, you can indeed change the association for text files but not for .pdf (as far as I understand). However, the additional note in the post of bpartch gave me the deciding hint. To make it easier for everybody, I provide an answer to my own question here. Thanks a lot @jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Edit -> Settings -> File Edit -> Filetype Associations` there is a checkbox that controls whether the associations should be the same as in the system settings. However, having this checkbox checked, my Filezilla still used Gimp to open .pdf-Files.

Therefore, I unchecked the checkbox and used customized associations as they can be defined in the Edit-box in the same window. Explanation is given in the dialogue itself but for my example, I used `pdf "/usr/bin/okular"` to make it work.

Hint: It seems like Filezilla does not have access to the `$PATH` variable and thus `pdf "okular"` does not work. Use the full path instead.